# How do I create a exported named function from a array of strings in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, named

Suppose I have made a function that I use to extract data.
This function would extract data from a json object.

This json object has the following type of structure:

```json
[
   "variable_name1",
   "value1",
   "value2",
   "value3",
],
[
   "variable_name2",
   "value1",
   "value2",
   "value3",
]
```

And so forth...

I want to create a function like this:

```js
export const myFunctionName1 = () => {
    return extractData(jsonObject[0]);
}

export const myFunctionName2 = () => {
    return extractData(jsonObject[1]);
}
```

Etcetera...

However, I want to simplify this into a for loop so that I can dynamically create the functions based on a name that I specify.

So for example:

```js
const variableNames = [
    "myFunctionName1",
    "myFunctionName2",
]
```

This variableNames Array, should be used to create functions based on the index.

So ideally I would do something like:

```js
for (const [index, name] of variableNames.entries()) {
    eval(`export const ${name} = () => {
        return extractData(jsonObject[${index + 1}]);
    }`);
}
```

EDIT (that should actually be an Array...):

```js
variableNames.forEach((name, index) => {
eval(`export const ${name} = () => {
        return extractData(jsonObject[${index + 1}]);
    }`);
});
```

This however, does not work.

I would also like to refrain from using eval, and would like to elsewhere be able to call: myFunctionName1() in a different script that imports it.

Is this possible? And if so, how would this be accomplished? It seems like a trivial task, but I'm having a hard time.

EDIT: I think I should just try and convert the JSON object structure into a different structure and use that instead of doing this wizardry.

EDIT: I could do something like this:

```js
const myFunctions = [
   const myFunctionName1 = () => { return extractData(jsonObject[0]); },
   const myFunctionName2 = () => { return extractData(jsonObject[1]); }
]
```

Etcetera, but I don't think it is very elegant. Ideally I would just map the variable_name to a function name and export that somehow.

Comment: That's not an object, it's an array, but you're missing the surrounding `[]`.

Comment: Don't use `eval()`. Create an object with all the exports, then export the object.

Comment: oh yeah my bad, variableNames.entries() wouldn't work here, derp...
I can create an object with all the exports, but that doesn't allow me to create a for loop, I'd have to manually create each function with the index.

Comment: Why doesn't that allow you to use a for loop? You can create object properties dynamically. `myFunctions[name] = () => extractData(jsonObject[index+1])`

Comment: I'm having a bit of a brain fart here, I've been coding all day and couldn't figure out I could just create an anonymous arrow function and assign it to an object. My head is a bit full of stuff, can't think clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create an object and dynamically add the functions to it.

Then simply call them like:

**callBacks.functionName()**

```js
function extractData(obj){
  return  obj
}
let jsonObject = [[
   "variable_name1",
   "value1",
   "value2",
   "value3",
],
[
   "variable_name2",
   "value1",
   "value2",
   "value3",
]];

let callBacks = {};

const variableNames = [
    "myFunctionName1",
    "myFunctionName2",
]

variableNames.forEach((f,index) => {
    callBacks[f] = () => {return extractData(jsonObject[index]);}
});

console.log(callBacks.myFunctionName1())
console.log(callBacks.myFunctionName2())
```

Comment: Ofcourse! That's it, I could just create a callbacks object. I just didn't know how to assign a callback property to an object but it's as simple as callbacks[f] within a forEach with an anonymous arrow function definition. Thank you <3